# PhpMyAdmin removes \n (new lines)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Using PhpMyAdmin 4.2.5,

I have a table when a field of type `text` on which I loaded content from plain text files (.txt) that had break lines on it (`\n`). When I first loaded the content using a PHP script the new line characters were preserved, but when I edit any of the rows on the phpMyAdmin interface and then save it, the new line characters are removed from the text field.

Any idea of how to fix this issue?

Edit:

After further testing, it seems that phpMyAdmin will remove any final \n after each addition, so if I load to the field:

```
A\n\nB
```

click the edit button and then save the new content will be:

```
A\nB
```

if I repeat the process the content will end up being just:

```
AB
```

This is an undesired behavior for plain text!

Any way of fixing it?

UPDATE:

It seems that @amenadiel found the answer, on their [changelog](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/changelog.php) the bug #4416 states:

> - bug #4416 New lines are removed when grid editing

So it seems that it is a problem with the version of phpMyAdmin I'm using, unfortunatelly the version that fixes the issue (4.3.0.0) has not been released yet. I will have to use some other client to edit the text. Thanks.

Comment: Does the field content positively change before and after edition? Have you tried outputting the field content in a php script outside of phpmyadmin?

Comment: @amenadiel: Yes, the content does change, the \n characters are removed. It seems like phpMyAdmin removes one \n after each edit, so if I add: A\n\nB click the edit button and then save the new content will be A\nB if I repeat the process the content will end up being AB =(

Comment: What is the procedure you are using for testing? Importing a text file or using the SQL window, or the fill-in form or what?

Comment: Weird. It doesn't happen to me, but do take a look at [bug #4416](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/changelog.php) in the changelog. It seems they broke something in the latest release.

Comment: If the content in the database is fine when adding rows with your php script, why trying to edit them with phpMyAdmin anyway? phpMyAdmin has a lot of flaws when it comes to "edit" data, actually it's not an application to maintain complex data.

Comment: @Megan Squire: I import the content using a php script and the content is fine, then I edit using the fill-in form (web interface of phpMyAdmin) and the \n are removed.

Comment: @Axel Amthor: It's a ton of txt files that need to be loaded, most of them won't need to be edited but some others will require changing some portions of the text. I was using phpMyAdmin because the content only needs to be edited once and creating some other custom interface its not worth it, furthermore I thought phpMyAdmin could handle such a simple edit just fine!!

Comment: why not upgrade to the latest version and see if thats still a problem, i have never seen phpmyadmin do this before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that @amenadiel found the answer, on their [changelog](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/changelog.php) the bug #4416 states:

> - bug #4416 New lines are removed when grid editing

So it seems that **it is a problem with the version of phpMyAdmin** I'm using, unfortunatelly the version that fixes the issue (4.3.0.0) has not been released yet.

Comment: you can go the other way and install an older version from before the bug was *added*